# how to avoid overlap text in result of PCA biplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggrepel, factoextra

the below plot obtains from this script, but much of the text is overlapping, I want to be displayed separately.

```
fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca,
                labelsize=3,
                addEllipses = T,
                repel=F,
                # Individuals
                geom.ind = "point",
                geom.var = c("point", "text"),
                fill.ind = data$Species,
                pointshape = 21 ,
                pointsize = 2,
                alpha.ind=0.4,
                # Variables
                alpha.var =1, 
                legend.title = list(fill = "Species"))+
  
  guides(color=guide_legend("Species"),fill= F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```r
repel=F
```

to

```r
repel=T
```

Comment: when using ```repel function``` equal True some points which important disappear